How can i use yosys as a library?
I want to use yosys features for program i am writing, it accepts verilog files from the user end and then i want to use it's rtlil representation for my program.
I tried using Kernel files directly in my program and it throws this error
g++  -I /usr/local/share/yosys/include main.cpp -o all
In file included from /usr/local/share/yosys/include/kernel/yosys.h:42,
                 from main.hh:8,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/share/yosys/include/kernel/yosys_common.h:60:4: error: #error It looks like you are trying to build Yosys without the config defines set. When building Yosys with a custom make system, make sure you set all the defines the Yosys Makefile would set for your build configuration.
   60 | #  error It looks like you are trying to build Yosys without the config defines set. \
      |    ^~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error


Yosys provides a yosys-config executable that allows you to build your C/C++ project in the same way and create a loadable plugin or link against the libyosys.so shared library. libyosys.so is undocummented, you can build it by running something like make ENABLE_LIBYOSYS=1.
